# Arduino leonardo + OV7670 non-FIFO

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I want to transfer image to PC via Arduino leonardo.
OV7670 is non-FIFO, and no SD card connected.
[image]

I followed this [blog](http://privateblog.info/arduino-uno-i-kamera-ov7670-primer-ispolzovaniya/) and this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8V-XBA2qAKY).using this [code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pHX-J7o86kvgr7zaC2tjA3JIkxs5vUgjcNxyGhLMabI/edit).
when uplaod, I got errors below:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"
error: 'ASSR' was not declared in this scope
error: 'EXCLK' was not declared in this scope
error: 'AS2' was not declared in this scope
error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
error: 'COM2A0' was not declared in this scope
error: 'WGM21' was not declared in this scope
error: 'WGM20' was not declared in this scope
error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope
error: 'WGM22' was not declared in this scope
error: 'CS20' was not declared in this scope
error: 'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope
error: 'UBRR0H' was not declared in this scope
error: 'UBRR0L' was not declared in this scope
error: 'UCSR0A' was not declared in this scope
error: 'UCSR0B' was not declared in this scope
error: 'RXEN0' was not declared in this scope
error: 'TXEN0' was not declared in this scope
error: 'UCSR0C' was not declared in this scope
error: 'UCSR0A' was not declared in this scope
```

I know that error occurred because this code is only for UNO. But mine is leonardo. Changing settings (Tool->board:uno board) was still compiling error.
I have search this [Topic](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=159557.0) found nothing. I am so confusing, please help.